# Split RGBW hex String into integers

Tags: c++, string

I have a program where the Arduino receives hex Strings that represent a RGBW color (similar to css for example). My goal is to create that color by using pwm, so I need to convert that one hex string into four integer values between 0..255 to use for the pwm.
Whats the best/easiest way to do this?

Example:

```
void incomingMessage(const MyMessage &message) {

    // h = hex value
    // message = e.g. (h) #112233AB
    redval = ?; // h11 => 17
    greenval = ?; // h22 => 34
    blueval = ?; // h33 = 51
    whiteval = ?; //AB = 171

    analogWrite(RED_PIN, redval);     
    analogWrite(GREEN_PIN, greenval);
    analogWrite(BLUE_PIN, blueval);
    analogWrite(WHITE_PIN, whiteval);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like using the String class because it can cause memory fragmentation. This would do it by just using C-style strings:

```
byte fromhex (const char * str)
  {
  char c = str [0] - '0';
  if (c > 9)
    c -= 7;
  int result = c;
  c = str [1] - '0';
  if (c > 9)
    c -= 7;
  return (result << 4) | c;
  }

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();

  const char * test = "#112233AB";

  byte redval   = fromhex (& test [1]);
  byte greenval = fromhex (& test [3]);
  byte blueval  = fromhex (& test [5]);
  byte whiteval = fromhex (& test [7]);

  Serial.println ((int) redval);
  Serial.println ((int) greenval);
  Serial.println ((int) blueval);
  Serial.println ((int) whiteval);

  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  // whatever   
  }  // end of loop
```

Output:

```
17
34
51
171
```

That does not do any validation (that the string is indeed 9 characters long, and contain hex characters) but I'll leave that for you to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to convert a pair of hexadecimal digits into a numeric value.  You also want to extract those values from a string.

The latter can be done using the [String.charAt()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringCharAt) method.  That allows you to extract individual characters from your string.

Then you need to convert those into a number.  There's a number of ways that could be done.

## strtol()

The strtol() function takes three parameters - the first is a C string (NULL-terminated char array) which contains the number you want to convert, the second you can ignore, and the third is the *base* to convert from.  So you could use something like:

```
char temp[3] = { char1, char2, NULL };
int val = strtol(temp, NULL, 16);
```

## Discrete functions

It's simple enough to write a function that converts a single hex digit into a value 0-15:

```
unsigned char h2d(unsigned char hex)
{
    if(hex > 0x39) hex -= 7; // adjust for hex letters upper or lower case
    return(hex & 0xf);
}
```

It's then simple enough to use that to make a function that takes two hex digits and converts them into a number:

```
unsigned char h2d2(unsigned char h1, unsigned char h2)
{
    return (h2d(h1)<<4) | h2d(h2);
}
```

There's as many ways of doing it as there are of skinning a cat (as the saying goes).  Every way has benefits and drawbacks though.  Of the two I have shown, to compare them:

- The first is "safer" as it has more error checking and can cope with other things besides hex values
- The second results in much smaller code but results with values other than hex digits are undefined.